# ASP.NET MVC - stored procedure execution returns invalid object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web app, and when I attempt to execute a stored procedure through the `.ExecuteReader()`, I get an "invalid object" error. I'm new to this so I'm not sure how to go about correcting it. I tried researching it but wasn't able to find an answer.

[image]

Please see my code below.

```
internal class CostCtrDAO
{
    private string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-54N4IDK\SQLSERVER2019;Initial Catalog=""Ceiling Database New"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

    //public string Cost_Center_Name { get; private set; }

    //internal List<CeilingByCostCtr> FetchAll()
    //{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    //performs all operations on the database - get all, create, delete, get one, search

    public List<CeilingByCostCtr> FetchAll()
    {
        //if (CostCtr is null)
        //{
        //    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(CostCtr));
        //}

        List<CeilingByCostCtr> returnList = new List<CeilingByCostCtr>();

        // Access the database
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.uspGetCostCtrByParam";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
            //command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Associate @CostCtr with parameter CostCtr
            // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCtr", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CostCtr;

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            CeilingByCostCtr ceilingByCostCtr = new CeilingByCostCtr();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ceilingByCostCtr.CostCtr = reader.GetString(0);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Cost_Center_Name = reader.GetString(1);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.BR = reader.GetString(2);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Branch_Name = reader.GetString(3);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Division = reader.GetString(4);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Division_Name = reader.GetString(5);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.New = reader.GetString(6);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Date = reader.GetString(7);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Type = reader.GetString(8);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Ref2 = reader.GetString(9);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Proj_Code = reader.GetString(10);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Proj_Name = reader.GetString(11);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Act_Code = reader.GetString(12);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Act_Name = reader.GetString(13);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.B_or_O = reader.GetString(14);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Jul = reader.GetString(15);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Aug = reader.GetString(16);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Sep = reader.GetString(17);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Oct = reader.GetString(18);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Nov = reader.GetString(19);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Dec = reader.GetString(20);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Jan = reader.GetString(21);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Feb = reader.GetString(22);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Mar = reader.GetString(23);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Apr = reader.GetString(24);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.May = reader.GetString(25);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Jun = reader.GetString(26);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Perm = reader.GetString(27);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Temp = reader.GetString(28);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.LimitedTerm = reader.GetString(29);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Monthly = reader.GetDecimal(30);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Analyst = reader.GetString(31);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.AvgPYs = reader.GetDecimal(32);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.CalcPEs = reader.GetDecimal(33);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Sal_Rate = reader.GetDecimal(34);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Auth = reader.GetDecimal(35);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Dollar_Adj = reader.GetDecimal(36);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Budget = reader.GetDecimal(37);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Mo_Rate = reader.GetDecimal(38);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Import = reader.GetString(39);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.BudgetYear = reader.GetInt32(40);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.OngoingStatus = reader.GetString(41);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.OneTimeEndingDate = reader.GetInt32(42);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Fund = reader.GetString(43);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Program = reader.GetString(44);
                    ceilingByCostCtr.Element = reader.GetString(45);

                    returnList.Add(ceilingByCostCtr);
                }
            }

            return returnList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will have to verify that the credentials that are being used to connect to the the database can see that stored proc and that you have the name of it correct. There's nothing in your code that you have posted that would say what is wrong either.

Comment: Oddly enough you can't select like that from a function either, even if it has no parameters, but you get a different error `Parameters were not supplied for the function ''.`

Answer (score 0):

If this `dbo.uspGetCostCtrByParam` is really a **stored procedure** in your database, then you should access it like this:

```
// Access the database
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.uspGetCostCtrByParam", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ....
    // possibly setting parameters here??
    ....
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // now iterate over the rows returned and get what you need
    }
}
```

You **cannot** run a `SELECT * FROM` to get the results of a stored procedure ...